# When should property observers run? What are the exceptions?

Tags: swift, properties, observers

The behavior of property observers surprises me in the following situation. I understand that observers do not recursively call themselves, but this behavior seems to carry over to different instances of the same class, and even to instances of different subclasses.

As I understand it, property observers run any time a property is set, even if the value doesn't change, except in initialization. What exactly are the exceptions to this rule? When exactly will property observers be disregarded as seen below?

```
var observersCalled = 0

class ClassOne {
    var relatedOne: ClassOne?
    var relatedTwo: ClassTwo?
    var property: String = "Initial" {
        didSet {
            observersCalled += 1
            relatedOne?.property = property
            relatedTwo?.property = property
        }
    }
}

class ClassTwo {
    var property: String = "Initial" {
        didSet {
            observersCalled += 1
        }
    }
}

class Subclass: ClassOne {
    override var property: String {
        didSet {
            observersCalled += 1
        }
    }
}

let thing = ClassOne()
thing.relatedOne = ClassOne()
thing.property = "New Value"
print(observersCalled) //1 (really?)

observersCalled = 0
thing.relatedOne = nil
thing.relatedTwo = ClassTwo()
thing.property = "Another Value"
print(observersCalled) //2 (makes sense)

observersCalled = 0
thing.relatedOne = Subclass()
thing.relatedTwo = nil
thing.property = "Yet Another Value"
print(observersCalled) //1 (really!?)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. I think you can refine the test case by dropping ClassTwo and Subclass and the related demonstrations. Also, I'd add a bool property (default false) on ClassOne and set it to true in the didSet observer. Then print("thing ran didSet: \(thing.didSetExecuted) [expected true]") and print("thing.related ran didSet: \(thing.relatedOne?.didSetExecuted) [expected true]"). Then submit the bug over at https://bugs.swift.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no exceptions. The behavior I asked about is a bug. I have submitted [a bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-419) for those tracking its progress.